# When should I be calling flush() on SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm new to SQLAlchemy and have inherited a somewhat messy codebase without access to the original author.

The code is litered with calls to `DBSession.flush()`, seemingly any time the author wanted to make sure data was being saved. At first I was just following patterns I saw in this code, but as I'm reading docs, it seems this is unnecessary - that autoflushing should be in place. Additionally, I've gotten into a few cases with AJAX calls that generate the error "InvalidRequestError: Session is already flushing".

Under what scenarios would I legitimately want to keep a call to flush()?

This is a Pyramid app, and SQLAlchemy is being setup with:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension(), expire_on_commit=False))
Base = declarative_base()
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `ZopeTransactionExtension` on the `DBSession` in conjunction with the `pyramid_tm` being active on your project will handle all commits for you. The situations where you need to flush are:

- You want to create a new object and get back the primary key.

  ```
  DBSession.add(obj)
  DBSession.flush()
  log.info('look, my new object got primary key %d', obj.id)
  ```
- You want to try to execute some SQL in a savepoint and rollback if it fails without invalidating the entire transaction.

  ```
  sp = transaction.savepoint()
  try:
      foo = Foo()
      foo.id = 5
      DBSession.add(foo)
      DBSession.flush()
  except IntegrityError:
      log.error('something already has id 5!!')
      sp.rollback()
  ```

In all other cases involving the ORM, the transaction will be aborted for you upon exception, or committed upon success automatically by `pyramid_tm`. If you execute raw SQL, you will need to execute `transaction.commit()` yourself or mark the session as dirty via `zope.sqlalchemy.mark_changed(DBSession)` otherwise there is no way for the ZTE to know the session has changed.

Also you should leave `expire_on_commit` at the default of `True` unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: Thanks so much. Follow up: What constitutes a really good reason to have expire_on_commit=False in this setup? (I dont know why it was set this way in the first place).

Comment: In my experience, it's used by people who don't know what they're doing and try to cheat the system by using objects after they have been committed. *obviously* after a commit, you have no guarantee that the state of that object is valid any longer.

Comment: @Michael Merickel - Very well explained. How about when we should not use flush()?  [Are there any side effects from calling SQLAlchemy flush() within code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338419/are-there-any-side-effects-from-calling-sqlalchemy-flush-within-code)